# Different citation style in a single article

Tags: biblatex, captions, citing

I am writing a document in Latex and citing with the `\cite` command. It gives the citation as

> A sentence <sup>10</sup>

Now for some places I want to give citation as just a number, no superscript as,

> A sentence 10

For this I created a new command as

```tex
\newcommand*{\citen}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \setcitestyle{numbers}%
    \cite{#1}%
  \endgroup   
}
```

Now using `\citen` gives a citation style I want for normal paragraph places but when I use this inside a figure caption, it gives this error,

```
Argument of \@iforloop has an extra }. }
Paragraph ended before \@iforloop was complete. }
```

How do I use the citation style I want inside the figure caption without altering the style in other places/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No Braces

### biblatex

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibopenbracket}{}
\renewcommand{\bibclosebracket}{}
\begin{document}
test\supercite{xxx}test\parencite{xxx}test\supercite{xxx}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test\supercite{xxx}test\parencite{xxx}test\supercite{xxx}}
\end{figure}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

## natbib

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand{\parencite}{m}{\begingroup\bibpunct{}{}{,}{n}{}{,}\cite{#1}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
test\cite{xxx}test\parencite{xxx}test\cite{xxx}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test\cite{xxx}test\parencite{xxx}test\cite{xxx}}
\end{figure}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Square Braces

### biblatex

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{document}
test\supercite{xxx}test\parencite{xxx}test\supercite{xxx}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test\supercite{xxx}test\parencite{xxx}test\supercite{xxx}}
\end{figure}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

## natbib

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super,square]{natbib}
\NewDocumentCommand{\parencite}{m}{\begingroup\citestyle{plain}\cite{#1}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
test\cite{xxx}test\parencite{xxx}test\cite{xxx}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test\cite{xxx}test\parencite{xxx}test\cite{xxx}}
\end{figure}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to remove the square braces around the citation number. I didn't use square braces around the reference number, but after using this all the other citation now has square braces around them.

Comment: @Eular I update answer.

Comment: Okay, now its all good. If possible please add some explanation.